# How to set POSIX message queues limit to unlimited in docker container using --ulimit option

Tags: docker, posix, ulimit

How to set the ***POSIX message queues limit as unlimited*** for docker container.

I know that --ulimit is an option that can be used along with docker run, but i'm not quite sure on how to use the --ulimit option along with docker run for POSIX message queues.

**tried following but did not work:**
`docker run -it --ulimit msgqueue=unlimited`

**Also tried following within container**
`ulimit -q unlimited`

**error**: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got to know that --ulimit in docker does not support the value unlimited**
**The way to do it is**

```
docker run -it --ulimit msgqueue=100000000:100000000
```

***100000000 is for 100GB***

Answer (score 3):

You can set POSIX message queues size to unlimited like this: `docker run --ulimit msgqueue=-1`. Tested it on Docker version `20.10.5`.

Within the container, you can confirm that it's indeed unlimited by running `ulimit -a`:

```
root@3385ae319f68:/# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15217
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 50000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) unlimited   # <----------
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

In my case, if I don't set the `--ulimit msgqueue=-1` option, the value is 819200.

Answer (score 0):

I use it together with other parameters:

```
docker run    -u "$(id -u)":"$(id -g)" \
          --sysctl fs.mqueue.queues_max=1024 \
          --sysctl fs.mqueue.msg_max=512 \
          --ulimit msgqueue=-1  \
....
```

If I open a second root Window (docker exec -it -u 0 bash) and set it there (ulimit -q unlimited) it works in this window only, which is not useful...